# How to test JAX-RS org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse?

Tags: kotlin, jax-rs, junit5

I have an app that is a heritage from a few years ago. It has JAX-RS and Spring Boot combined.

I have to unit-test `@Controller`, which is a JAX-RS class annotated as `@Component`.
I am getting a response `OutboundJaxrsResponse`. The class itself is sealed and doesn't allow me to do much with it.

Is it possible to translate it into something more testable as I care only about `status` and `reason`?

**COMMENT:**

I don't want to make `Response.ok().build()` as it neglects why I am testing. I would expect to do something like this as I use JUnit5:

```
assertEquals("My response", entity(response))
assertEquals(200, response.status)
```

I searched for different solutions, but JAX-RS seemed to have different approaches for testing it, but I cannot find a convenient and working one.

**UPDATE:**

I have defined endpoint this way:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{key}")
open override fun getStatus(@PathParam("key") key: String): Response {
    return try {
        Response.status(
            Response.Status.OK.statusCode,
            "This okay"
        ).build()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Response.status(
            Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.statusCode,
            "Error, resource not found"
        ).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `response.getEntity()` `response.getStatus()`. What's the actual problem you're facing? What's so "sealed" about it? What code are you actually testing?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha response.getEntity() always returns null even though the entity isn't  null. response.readEntity() doesn't work for OutboundJaxrsResponse.

Comment: Output I am getting when printout the object: `OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=404, reason=Missing Resources, hasEntity=false, closed=false, buffered=false}`

Note: I don't use an object before the assertion, so it isn't an exhausted stream or something.

Comment: I can't really help if I can't see the code you're trying to test. Or at least an example that demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My confusion came as I didn't see any expected fields in the `org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundJaxrsResponse` object such as `entity`, `content`, `body` or similar.

To overcome the issue, in my case I have to use `response.statusInfo.reasonPhrase` which works as I expect.

```
val ID = "abc"
val response: Response = controller.getInfoBy(ID)

assertEquals("ID: abc", response.statusInfo.reasonPhrase)
assertEquals(200, response.status)
```

**NOTE:** statusInfo contains many other useful fields to retrieve info of the response.